# Is it possible to do calculus in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, math, cas

What I mean is differentiation and integration, stuff that a CAS would do? (like a Typical handheld CAS if not better.)

Is this possible? What gem(s) would I need to install? Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Numerical or symbolical?

Comment: "Is it possible?" Someone please remove that question, of course it is, if ruby is turing complete.

Comment: Please check Numo::NArray https://github.com/ruby-numo/numo-narray

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few gems - in different states of development and completeness - that help increase the "mathing" power of Ruby:

- [**`numo-linalg`**](https://github.com/ruby-numo/numo-linalg) Linear Algebra Library for Ruby/Numo::NArray
- [**`nmatrix`**](https://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix) Dense and sparse linear algebra library for Ruby via SciRuby
- [**`rb-gsl`**](https://github.com/SciRuby/rb-gsl) Ruby interface to the GNU Scientific Library
- [**`daru`**](https://github.com/SciRuby/daru) Data Analysis in Ruby
- [**`mathn`**](https://github.com/ruby/mathn) Deprecated library that extends math operations
- [**`mathematical`**](https://github.com/gjtorikian/mathematical) Convert mathematical equations to SVGs, PNGs, or MathML

Unfortunately, Ruby as a language has mostly been used for rapid web application prototyping and development and *NOT* scientific analysis or data science. Thus, it's capabilities in this area - when compared to other languages such as a Python - are still somewhat lacking.