# ruby analysis (math) class

Tags: ruby, analysis

I am wondering, if there is a analysis class for ruby? Analysis as in being able to derive and integrate and such things. Can be numeric if it cant handle the analytic way.

Google search hasn't turned up anything.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in library to do this. There are a few gems though that will help you perform Calculus operations in Ruby such as [Symbolic](https://github.com/brainopia/symbolic).

There's another StackOverflow thread discussing the same topic: [Calculus in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994920/calculus-in-ruby)